# how to instantiate broadcast receiver in class that does not extend activity or service

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a utility class that needs to be able to receive broadcast intents from another class. This utility class does not extend either Activity or Service.  How do I instantiate and register the broadcast receiver in this class?

Because the class is not an Activity class, there is no onCreate or onDestroy callback methods.  The only place to put register receiver is in the constructor, but there is no onDestroy method so i cannot find a place to put the unregister receiver call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the utility class an instance of your application `Context` and you can use it to register receivers.  If you need to run code that responds to an intent, you *must* use and `Activity` or `Service`.  That's Android.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to do this. You are essentially asking how to instantiate a class that needs to rely on the activity lifecycle without relying on the activity lifecycle. I suggest you refactor to have your code get called in onCreate() and onDestroy() instead. Keep in mind though, that Activities can be created and destroyed at any time. If you are using multiple Activities in your application, you will run into problems receiving broadcasts as you switch from one Activity to another.